# It doesn't align in center

Tags: html, wordpress, html-table

I was using this code in my wordpress theme to align in center it didn't work, but if  I align right or left it works:

```
  <table border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style='width: 435px; height: 90px; background-image: url( http://vortex.accuweather.com/adcbin/netweather_v2/backgrounds/spring1_435x90_bg.jpg ); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #607041;' >
       <div id='NetweatherContainer' style='height: 75px;' >
        <script src='http://netweather.accuweather.com/adcbin/netweather_v2/netweatherV2ex.asp?partner=netweather&tStyle=normal&logo=1&zipcode=MEA|AE|AE005|DUBAI|&lang=eng&size=10&theme=spring1&metric=0&target=_self'></script>
     </div>
     <div style='text-align: center; font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px; color: #FDEA11;' >
      <a style='color: #FDEA11' href='http://www.accuweather.com/world-index-forecast.asp?partner=netweather&locCode=MEA|AE|AE005|DUBAI|&metric=1' >Forecast</a> | <a style='color: #FDEA11' href='http://www.accuweather.com/maps-satellite.asp' >Maps</a> | <a style='color: #FDEA11' href='http://www.accuweather.com/index-radar.asp?partner=accuweather&zipcode=MEA|AE|AE005|DUBAI|' >Radar</a>
     </div>
     <img style='float: right; padding-right: 5px;' src='http://vortex.accuweather.com/adc2004/common/images/misc/netweather_v2/adcwhite.png' /><div style='clear: both;' />
   </div>
 </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is show an image, just center the container of that rather than using a `table` element:

```
.ad {
    display: block;
    margin:  0 auto;
}
.w435 {
    width:   435px;
}
```

Then give your `div` a width (which you already have):

```
<div class="ad w435"><!-- content --></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SQ9Qn/